# Are there English equivalents to a Japanese old saying, “Be the mouth of cock rather than remaining as the tail of ox”?

Tags: expressions, proverbs

Every time I hear about the success story of entrepreneurs such as IT business, not to mention Apple, Microsoft, and Soft Bank founders, an old Japanese saying, 鶏口となるとも牛後となる勿れ‐“(Choose to) be the mouth of a cock rather than ending up as the tail of an ox,” comes to my mind.

I understand this maxim was imported from Chinese saying, “寧為鶏口、勿為牛後 – ning wei ji kou wu nju hou” (If I quote wrong, please correct) which has the exactly same meaning.

The mouth of a cock and the tail of an ox are compared to the leader or owner of small company / organization (with a big prospect for growing up as a big company in the end) and just common office workers of big companies.

Are there any equivalent English sayings that encourage someone who is ambitious enough to start up his / her own company or challenging new business by spinning out from their old organization?

Comment: There's also an equivalent Hebrew statement - "better to be the head of foxes than the tail of lions".

Comment: @Avner Shahar-Kashtan. Is it also in English? It very much resembles "Better be the mouth of cock than the tail of ox."

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan actually, the original Hebrew source is the reverse: והוי זנב לאריות ואל תהי ראש לשועלים, better to be the tail of lions then the head of foxes.  Mishna, Avos 4:15.  For explanation see the commentary of Rabbenu Yonah.

Comment: I misread the title of the question; I really need to get my mind out of the gutter.

Comment: We have a similar saying in America:
"Like a boss"

Comment: @Boss We do, do we? New one on me. And kinda strange.  Sure, it is said that “it is good to be the king”, but me personally, I’d rather be somebody who gets something done than somebody who just sits around and tells other people to do things.

Comment: @tchrist It is something "the young people™" say. ;)

Comment: @Boss "like a boss" doesn't exactly mean that. It is quite a different thing, actually. It's about the attitude someone is having while dealing with any kind of thing, it's not a business advice.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The following comes to mind:

> Better to be a big fish in a little pond than a little fish in a big
> pond.

Although for 鶏口となるも牛後となるなかれ, [Kotowaza Dictionary](https://kotowaza-dictionary.jp/k0010/)
gives the following, which I personally had never heard:

> Better be the head of a dog than the tail of a lion.
>
> Better be first in a village than second at Rome.

Comment: @Curious-proofreader.Thanks to your input (Kotowaza Alguide com.) I leaned that the axiom, “寧為鶏口、勿為牛後” is from 苏秦列伝. (Chronicle of Sū Qín Dinasty) of 史記 (History) written by司马迁 - sī mǎ qiān (BC 139 - BC 86) from this source . It’s a great discovery to know that the phrase, “Be the mouth of a cock rather than ending up as the tail of an ox” has been on the mouth of people for more than 2100 years.

Comment: I've never heard the kotowaza-allguide sayings before either. Big fish in a little pond is **massively** more common.

Comment: This may be more of a cultural than semantic distinction, but my impression is that the Chinese/Japanese saying is uniformly positive. This is NOT the case with the English "big fish in a small pond." The English phrase is often used in situations where it's implied that the small pond is limiting and the big pond is better--for example, you might say a high school athlete is a "big fish in a small pond"--he looks better than he is because his competition is weak.

Comment: @Curious-proofreader. I made a great mistake in the above comment. 蘇秦列伝 of sī mǎ qiān’s “History” isn’t the Chronicle of Sū Qín Dynasty. It is the Story of 蘇秦 (Sū Qín), a prominent diplomat in the Age of the Warring States in China (BC403-BC221). He was well-known for his eloquence and diplomatic skills that made him succeed in forming six-country alliance in Eastern part of China against the formidable 秦(Qin). “Be the mouth of a cock rather than the tail of an ox” appears in Sū Qín story.

Comment: I have never heard nor seen “it is better to be a big fish in a small pond than a small fish in a big pond”, so I think this answer is more “synthesizing a parallel” from an English-language idiom than stating an equivalent idiom. Moreover, this synthetic parallel has the *opposite* sentiment to the actual English language idiom from which it is constructed: “Joe is a big fish in a small pond” is used pejoratively to imply that he has an inflated sense of self-importance, and that his actual talent, skills, or capabilities wouldn't survive fair comparison with a large peer group.

Comment: @chapka Yes but that phrase borrows from the one listed in the answer. I would say "Better to be a big fish in a small pond than a small fish in a big one" is just as positive and has the same meaning as the phrase in the OP, but because it is common, "big fish in a small pond" has "leaked" out into more general usage.

Comment: The "second in Rome" quote is [attributed to Julius Caesar](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Julius_Caesar#Attributed).

Comment: The fish quote is sometimes given the other way around too.

Comment: Unless we are talking about absolute total power, then most likely the "second in Rome" has much more power than the "first in a random village". Of course if the first one has absolute power, everything changes.

Answer (score 35):

It may seem like a long shot but consider the quote from Milton's *Paradise Lost*:

***Better to reign in Hell, than serve in Heaven.***

even though it may carry additional (sarcastic ?) meaning.

Comment: In Book 11 of Homer's Odyssey when Odysseus goes down to the Underworld and meets Achilles (who, of course, had been a famous warrior and ruler of men), the latter speaks this famous line: "I’d rather serve as another man’s labourer, as a poor peasant without land, and be alive on Earth, than be lord of all the lifeless dead." I think it's safe to assume that Milton was responding to this (and there's a lot of intertexuality with Homer in Paradise Lost) with the quoted line he gives to Satan.

Comment: Interesting - I've heard exactly the opposite: "Better to serve in Heaven than to reign in Hell."

Comment: @Kevin I would guess that, since the statement comes from Satan himself, Christians have inverted it, as they obviously do not agree with Satan.

Answer (score 18):

I have heard the expression "Better to live one day as a lion than spend a lifetime as a sheep" used in that context.

Comment: I think this has a very different meaning.

Answer (score 8):

To the extent that the original saying is about being in front (leading)
versus being behind (and is about animals),

> If you’re not the lead dog, the view never changes.

seems to fit. 
It got nearly 100,000,000 hits on Google.

Comment: It is often accomplished by the obvious illustration.

Comment: Doesn't have anywhere near 100,000,000 hits on Google. [I see 107,000](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8CDyp.png)

Comment: When I Google `you the lead dog never changes` I get “[About 98,700,000 results](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5O8nz.png)”, including variants like “Unless you’re the lead dog, ….”, “If Yourre Not The Lead Dog ….”, “If you ain’t the lead dog ….” and even “if you ain the lead dog ….”, etc. Also, some end with “… the scenery never changes.”

Comment: I think you misunderstand the figures there! Googling `dog` shows 360 million results. Googling `dog view` over 1 billion so that must be the number matching either of the terms. Not both of them. To search for phrases you need to use quotes.

Comment: I concede that Google search is inscrutable, but it looks like a search for the exact phrase, in quotes, finds none of the variants that I listed. These variants are clearly just trivially different ways of expressing (and even different ways of spelling) the saying, and, as such, I believe that they should count towards a measure of its popularity and recognition factor. Obviously, I didn’t look through all 98 million hits; some of them are probably just occurrences of one or two of the words. So perhaps a more meaningful number is one somewhere between yours and mine.

Comment: -1: this answer is untrue, and @Scott seems more interested in not losing face than making it true. This is also not the reply I expected to "360M results for «dog»": `Obviously, I didn’t look through all 98 million hits; some of them are probably just occurrences of one or two of the words.`

Answer (score 6):

A common expression used to convey the concept is:

> Better to be a [leader](http://www.insidebusiness360.com/index.php/article-list/Why+it+is+better+to+be+a+leader+than+a+follower+in+business/2321553/) than a follower:
>
> In the business world, there are leaders and there are followers. Some people seem to have been born leaders and others develop leaderships skills over the years. There are many benefits to being a leader in your chosen professional field.

Source: http://www.insidebusiness360.com

Comment: This doesn't contain the distinction between big and small organizations that's contained in the original expression.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a Romanian saying on the same subject:

> "Better be outstanding in the village, than mediocre in the city"

or, in original Romanian:

> "Mai bine fruntaş la sat decât codaş la oraş".

Comment: Interesting. This Romanian saying very much resembles "Better first in village than second in Rome" cited by @CuriousProofreader. Possiblly came from the same root.

Answer (score 2):

"Better to die on your feet than live on your knees."

"I would rather be a big fish in a little pond."

"Better a live dog than a dead lion."

(Each of these is occasionally reversed, according to taste.)

Comment: It seems the third of those goes against the other two (and most of the other suggestions on this question)

Comment: @Kevin -- yeah, each of them is reversible, but the third one is more often heard that way, dunno why.

Answer (score 2):

I actually don't agree with the current, chosen answer.

**The Why of It**

"Be the mouth of a male-chicken than the tail of an ox", to me, means this:

> Strive to be a leader, heard and respected by others, instead of being a forgotten, unimportant person

A male-chicken (that is, a cock, but I'd rather not refer to it as a cock) screams loudly every morning; everyone heeds the screams of a male-chicken, for it means a new day has come and everyone gets up from their bed; the tail of an ox is pretty much forgotten until it causes trouble

**What Others Are Saying**

I am simply telling my interpretations here:

> Better to be a big fish in a little pond than a little fish in a big pond.

This actually means **you should find worse people to hang around with instead of bettering yourself**. For example, if your academic scores are average, you should go to a lower-ranking school filled with less-knowledgable students to make your scores relatively good. While this does carry a similar outcome (that is, you're seen as a leader instead of falling behind), this carries a negative meaning. Another interpretation would be that you should find a range you're comfortable with, but it's just a sugar-coating

> Better to reign in Hell, than serve in Heaven.

This simply means that **you should find a job you're happy with**. Seriously, think about it: Satan didn't like having to do what God (his boss) told him to (serve in Heaven), so in spite he found a job he'd rather have: reign in Hell. When you strip out all the religious symbols, the meaning becomes simple and is actually pretty positive.

The closest one that I think should be the answer is @Josh61's

> Better to be a leader than a follower

I just feel that the tail of an ox does not imply a "follower", instead more like an unimportant person

Comment: "Rooster" is the word you may be looking for. American English prefers it while British English prefers "cock" for male chicken.

Answer (score 1):

Also of note as a related sentiment, though perhaps not as direct an equivalent as other answers presented herein, may be found in Shakespeare's Julius Caeser:

> Cowards die many times before their deaths
>   The valiant never taste of death but once.
>
> > Julius Caeser, Act II, Scene II

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see how this is even remotely equivalent.

Comment: Well, not equivalent, but as I indicated in my answer, a related sentiment. The original idiom appears to mean something like, "It's better to lead than follow, even if you're leading a small group vs. following in a large group."

Comment: I hit enter too soon: continued...

Also containing implicit nuances about the unpleasant proximity to an ox's anus.

Caesar seemed to mean that the valiant live better, suffering only a single (albeit final) unpleasantness, while the less valiant (in the business context, workers rather than founders & entrepreneurs) may suffer both their own and their peers' slings & arrows. 

So, if the context is the wisdom of not fearing entrepreneurial action instead of office-dronedom, saying "It's better to lead than follow" could be replaced with "Valiant die only once, cowards many times."